# Python - Merging 2 lists to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

For example

```
a = [a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

The output should be a dictionary which will look like:

```
{'a':6, 'b':8, 'c':10, 'd':12}
```

I tried using zip but it just overwrites the values.

Comment: How is "merging two lists" defined?

Comment: into a dictionary

Comment: It looks like you want to add the integers in `b` that correspond to the same letter key in `a`. You need to say that explicitly in your question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = list("abcdabcd")
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

d = defaultdict(int)
for key, val in zip(a,b):
    d[key] += val
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears you want the sum of the corresponding numbers as your values.

I would suggest using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) to manage your unique keys, and implement the summation yourself:

```
import collections

a, b, c, d = "abcd"
a = [a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

result = collections.defaultdict(int)

for k,v in zip(a,b):
    result[k] += v
```

A `defaultdict(int)` will create an integer with no initial value (which means '0' by default) when you lookup a key that does not already exist in the dictionary. So you will get 0 + value + value ... for each key, which appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: It's in the OP's code. I assume he has them defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try without default dict , Here is recipe :

```
a = "abcdabcd"
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

no_dublicate={}
for item in zip(list(a),b):
    if item[0] not in no_dublicate:
        no_dublicate[item[0]]=[item[1]]
    else:
        for key,value in no_dublicate.items():
            if value==no_dublicate[item[0]]:
                no_dublicate[item[0]]=item[1]+int("".join(str(x) for x in value))

print(no_dublicate)
```

output:

```
{'d': 12, 'c': 10, 'a': 6, 'b': 8}
```